# Domain Model + Data Mapper: сохранение коллекции связанных объектов

Tags: проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

В некотором текстовом редакторе для представления документа и его правок используется реализация шаблона проектирования *Модель Предметной Области* ([Domain Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model)).

Иерархия моделей предметной области имеет следующий вид (лишние детали опущены):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь, экземпляр документа (`Document`) управляет своими изменениями (`Change`), связанными в коллекцию изменений (`ChangeCollection`). После внесения изменений в документ, вызывается метод `Document::applyChanges` при этом не важно кто именно делает этот вызов (сам объект `Document` или клиентский код). В случае, если предыдущее изменение было сделано тем же пользователем, что и текущее, последнее изменение в истории правок обновляется. Иначе создается новое изменение.

Работа с правками проводится преимущественно в экземпляре `Document`, но сами правки могут быть переданы клиентскому коду. Примером такой передачи может служить метод `Document::getHistory`, возвращающий всю историю правок документа (например, для построения журнала изменений). Это означает, что любая правка может быть изменена (например, через `Change::setDescription`) без явного уведомления об этом факте коллекции правок (`ChangeCollection`).

Для сохранения этой иерархии классов в БД используется реализация шаблона *Преобразователь данных* ([DataMapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern)):

[image: Иерархия DataMapper]

В этой схеме, `DocumentMapper` имеет ссылку на `ChangeMapper` чтобы иметь возможность загружать/сохранять связанные изменения. При вызове `DocumentMapper::save` автоматически вызывается `ChangeMapper::save` для каждого элемента коллекции `Document::history`.

---

Проблемы начинаются, когда у каждого документа может быть не одна правка, а несколько сотен. Принудительное сохранение каждой правки приводит к существенным расходам машинного времени.

**Собственно вопрос**: каким образом правильнее всего учитывать изменения правок и сохранять только новые/удаленные/измененные?

Сразу оговорюсь, интересуют именно проектные решения, не основанные на специфических приемах того или иного языка программирования.

Comment: *"у каждого документа может быть не одна правка, а несколько сотен."* -- это в течение одного сеанса работы с документом или вообще? *"и сохранять только новые"* -- когда вы загружаете документ, все старые правки тоже загружаете? Т.е. для каждого документа вы храните всю историю изменений? Можете более детально пояснить вашу архитектуру?

Comment: _"Document управляет своими изменениями, связанными в ChangeCollection"_ -- ок. а дальше _"правка может быть изменена без уведомления ChangeCollection"_ -- получается, что Document не управляет изменениями.

Comment: @andreycha, "_у каждого документа может быть не одна правка, а несколько сотен._" -- вообще. Правки это набор сущностей, которые хранятся все время (аналог истории правок на stackoverflow), а не только в течении открытого сеанса. "_когда вы загружаете документ, все старые правки тоже загружаете?_"  -- тут могут быть варианты. По-хорошему используется Lazy Load для загрузки коллекции правок при первом обращении к ним.

Comment: @Stack, вы правы, здесь есть неточность. Для примера, я добавил метод `Document::getHistory`, возвращающий коллекцию правок. Каждая правка, это отдельная сущность, с собственным API, изолированным от самого документа. Мне кажется неправильно замыкать работу с правками на API класса `Document`.

Comment: _"каким образом правильнее всего учитывать изменения правок"_ -- создайте очередь. правок. обработчик очереди может просмаривать эту очередь и что не надо - игнорировать.

Comment: @Stack, вы имеете в виду очередь изменений объектов `Change`? А кто их туда будет отправлять?

Comment: _"А кто их туда будет отправлять?"_ -- про правки у вас в вопросе: "изменения изменение было сделано тем же пользователем". если их создает агент/пользователь, то он их и отправляет.

Comment: @Stack, увы, это не выход. В таком случае, вместо компактной реализации `ChangeDataMapper` у меня получится размазывание ссылок на объект очереди по всей системе (каждый должен знать, как добавить туда измененный объект `Change`).

Comment: @Stack, мне такой подход чем-то напоминает реализацию шаблона `Unit Of Work`.

Comment: *"правки могут быть переданы клиентскому коду ... Это означает, что любая правка может быть изменена"* -- а вот это как-то сомнительно выглядит. Зачем кому-то менять правки? И что он потом делает с этими изменениями? Судя по вашей диаграмме отдельно взятая правка не имеет привязки к документу и вообще ничего не означает сама по себе. `Document` и метод `applyChanges` выглядит как идеальное *единственное* место управления правками документа. Тем более что при сохранении документа правки тоже сохраняются.

Comment: @andreycha, для примера, посмотрите на то, как устроена система правок вопросов на stackoverflow. Даже после фиксации правки, у пользователей есть возможно изменить любую (не только последнюю) редакцию. Это может быть полезно для изменения атрибутов собственно правки (например, комментария о сделанных изменениях)

Comment: Понял. Разумно. А как потом эта исправленная правка сохраняется? И создается ли новая правка или изменяется уже существующая?

Comment: @andreycha, в случае со stackoverflow при изменении правки происходит создание новой ревизии (с откатом состояния + применением новых изменений). В моем случае, я скорее предполагаю изменение _только_ одной правки из истории (например, комментарий или другая мета-информация), без изменения самого документа и истории правок в целом.

Comment: @andreycha, другой типичный юзкейс -- удаление старых правок из истории. Критерии "старости" при этом определяются в самом документе (это типичное бизнес-правило), но в ряде случаев должна быть возможность для внешнего кода избавиться от устаревших (не актуальных) изменений. При таком подходе, нужно как-то фиксировать удаление объектов `Change`, но делать это на уровне `Document` нельзя из-за того что сам метод удаления находится в API вложенного объекта (`Document::history`)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev чешется написать ответ, но я понимаю, что полностью не понимаю вашей архитектуры :). А от отвлеченных размышлений на эту тему много пользы не будет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34707/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-andreycha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

Самое простое решение — отслеживать изменение экземпляров `Change` собственными средствами этого класса. Для этого можно создать метод `Change::isModified`. А изменение состава коллекции проще всего отслеживать на уровне самой коллекции.

## Исследование по теме вопроса

После проведения небольшого исследования по теме вопроса оказалось, что есть сразу несколько способов решения проблемы. Они отличаются как по степени гибкости, так и по педантичности разделения функционала системы на отдельные "слои". Данное исследование не претендует на полноту, поэтому я мог что-то упустить.

К сожалению, ни одно из этих решений не прозвучало в ответах на вопрос, поэтому приведу их все.

1. Реализовать контроль добавления/удаления объектов в коллекции (`ChangeColletion`), а контроль изменений в самих объектах `Change`.

   Этот путь невероятно прост, особенно если для доступа к свойствам модели `Change` используются только специальные геттеры/сеттеры. Из минусов этого решения можно выделить необходимость внесения в интерфейс класса `Change` метода `isModified`, который не имеет ценности в рамках бизнес-логики приложения.

   UML диаграмма<sup>*</sup> для этого случая может иметь вид:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Реализовать контроль добавления/удаления объектов в коллекции (`ChangeColletion`) (аналогично п. 1). При этом, контроль изменения объектов `Change` проводить в коллекции `ChangeCollection` на основе заранее сохраненных "эталонных копий" элементов коллекции.

   Из минусов можно выделить необходимость хранения сразу двух объектов `Change` для каждого из элементов коллекции: эталонного и изменяемого. Кроме того, необходимо реализовать механизм сравнения объектов `Change`, что в ряде случаев может быть проблематично.

   UML диаграмма классов<sup>*</sup> для этого случая может иметь вид:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Использовать классическую реализацию шаблона *Единица Работы* ([*Unit of Work*](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/unit-of-work.html)).

   Экземпляр единицы работы создается в `ChangeMapper` при загрузке `ChangeCollection` и регистрируется в экземплярах `ChangeCollection` и `Change`. При каждом изменении состояния коллекции, она уведомляет об этом экземпляр `UnitOfWork`. В свою очередь, при изменении экземпляров `Change` они так же сообщают об этом факте. При сохранении коллекции элементов в БД, экземпляр `UnitOfWork` извлекается из коллекции элементов и на его основе генерируются традиционные Create/Update/Delete запросы к БД.

   Из минусов стоит отметить некоторую громоздкость реализации, и необходимость в явном виде передавать экземпляр `UnitOfWork` всем заинтересованным сторонам. API классов `Change` и `ChangeCollection` (как, впрочем, и логика их работы) так же пополнятся дополнительными методами имеющими смысл только для правильного сохранения в БД.

   UML диаграмма классов<sup>*</sup> для этого случая может иметь вид:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Реализовать шаблон проектирования *Наблюдатель* ([*Observer*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)) в классах `Change` и `ChangeCollection`.

   При каждом изменении состава коллекции элементов или состояния самих элементов создается событие, которое может быть обработано любым участником системы. При загрузке объектов в экземпляре `ChangeMapper` этот экземпляр регистрирует себя как наблюдатель, и ведет "журнал изменений" состояния `ChangeCollection` и вложенных `Change`. При сохранении именно этот журнал и используется для определения новых/удаленны/измененных объектов `Change`. При желании, функционал "журнала изменений" можно вынести в отдельный класс и использовать композицию для его связи с `ChangeMapper`.

   Этот подход является наиболее общим. Новый API, связанный с реализацией шаблона *Наблюдатель* может быть легко вовлечен в бизнес-логику приложения. Однако нужно понимать, что если слой бизнес-логики не проектировался для работы с событиями с самого начала, то API наблюдения все так же будет использоваться только для сохранения объектов в БД. Другой недостаток подобного решения заключается в увеличении общей сложности системы

   UML диаграмма классов<sup>*</sup> для этого подхода может иметь вид:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Можно использовать не изменяемые объекты `Change`.

   При необходимости внесения изменений создается новый экземпляр `Change`, который регистрируется в коллекции `ChangeCollection` с помощью ее же методов. Тогда, вся информация о изменениях доступна в экземпляре коллекции и может быть легко получена при сохранении. Например, можно хранить *ссылки* на оригинальный состав коллекции и при необходимости сравнивать их со *ссылками* на объекты из текущего состава. (Сравнение ссылок на объекты существенно проще, чем сравнение самих объектов, поэтому нет нужны в лишней памяти для хранения дубликатов объектов как в п. 2.)

   При желании, можно реализовать шаблон *Декоратор* ([*Decorator*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)) для изоляции собственно коллекции, и логики отслеживания ее изменений.

   Из сложностей, стоит отметить неестественность такого подхода в традиционных ОО-системах. Это скорее путь радикального функционального программирования.

   UML диаграмма<sup>*</sup> такого решения может иметь вид:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>* Все приведенные UML диаграммы существенно упрощены. Из них выброшено все, что не относится на прямую к делу.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

На вашем месте я бы прибегнул к использованию паттернов [`CQRS`](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) + [`Event Sourcing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn589792.aspx)(без message queue). Так как это архитектурные паттерны, в пару строк кода не продемонстрировать и на пальцах не объяснить. Но в интернете не мало статей на эту тему и примеров.

Comment: Под Event Sourcing вы понимаете PubSub?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn589792.aspx например

Comment: Понял. Но связка _CQRS_ + _Event Sourcing_, на мой взгляд, плохо сочетается с _Domain Model_ + _Data Mapper_. Если применение _CQRS_ для расщепления _Domain Model_ еще имеет смысл, то применение _Event Sourcing_ потребует полного пересматривания архитектуры.

Comment: Немного изменил ваш ответ, добавив ссылки на шаблоны. Надеюсь вы не обидитесь :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нет конечно, спасибо :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev на самом деле CQRS тоже потребует пересмотра архитектуры :) Однако поставленная задача в  таком случае будет решаться на уровне ядра программы.

Comment: То, что я описал в вопросе, это далеко не все приложение, а только куски слоев бизнес-логики и источника данных. Поэтому пересматривать архитектуру приложения полностью мне не очень хочется. Но все равно спасибо вам за новые идеи. +1